# Python alphabet shifting string

Tags: python, algorithm

i have tried but can't seem to find my mistake in my code.
My code is suppose to switch all the alphabetic characters (like a/aa/A/AA) and do nothing with the rest but when i run the code it doesn't give an error yet do what i want.

Could anyone tell me what i have done wrong or have forgotten?

```
letter = input("type something")
shift = int(input("type how many shifts"))
if letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']:
    a = ord(letter) + shift
    b = chr(a)
    print(b)
else: 
    print(letter)
```

EDIT: thanks for the == replacement for in! Does someone know why using more than one character in letter gives the same print?(Desired output: when i put in abc and 1 i want it to print bcd)

Comment: Well what *does* it do? Give a [mcve].

Comment: If you want it to make you a margarita you're going to need to try a different approach. If you're not trying to make margaritas it would help if you explained your *desired output*.

Comment: so sorry forgot to do it

Comment: **Desired output**.

Comment: Use `isalpha()` to check for letters, Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558392/how-to-check-if-character-in-string-is-a-letter-python

Comment: Give an simple input/output example will be the best way to give a vision of your problem

Comment: `if letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']:`

Comment: is there another way than using islower and isupper?

Comment: Desired output means you should put something like "*When I put in 'frobnosticate' and 2, I expect that it will output `fizz buzz`, but it prints `crazy time` instead*."

Comment: Done, thanks i'm new to this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to shift the letters so if the input letter is 'a' and shift is 3, then the output should be 'd'.

In that case replace

```
if letter == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']:
```

with

```
if letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']:
```

Or better yet as Tempux suggested you can use

```
if letter.isalpha()
```

If you want to shift multple letters you need to loop across each character. Try the following code for multiple letters

```
letter = input("type something")
shift = int(input("type how many shifts"))
s = ""
for l in letter:
    if l.isalpha():
        a = ord(l) + shift
        s += chr(a)
    else: 
        s += l

print(s)
```

Comment: He mentioned that he want "the amount of shifts"

Comment: i'm pretty sure he meant the letter after the amount of shifts, because the amount is something the user enters in the first place

Comment: Omg thanks such an easy fix, i do have another problem now, when i try multiple letters nothing happens...

Comment: @Omar I edited the answer with code when multiple letters are entered. If it works please accept the answer.

Comment: @shubham003 it indeed works but i haven't had isalpha in class yet so i may not use it. Is there no other way than using this?

Comment: Instead of if l.isalpha() you can use if l in ['a','b','c',...].

Answer (score 1):

```
#a is the string you want to encrypt, b is the number you shift by
a,b = input().split()
x = int(b)
#code to make sure that the shift is less than 26
for i in range(x):
  if x > 26:
    x = x - 26
  else:
    break
#driver code
print(''.join(map(chr,([ord(c)+x for c in a]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare letter with list, but i think you want to check for contain letter in list, so you should just replace `==` to `in`

Comment: thanks a lot! like i mentioned on shubbam103 i do have another problem still where multiple letters don't work....

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, I'd say you're more after something like this:

```
import string
text = input("type something> ")
shift = int(input("enter number of shifts> "))
for letter in text:
    index = ord(letter) - ord('a') + shift
    print(string.ascii_letters[index % len(string.ascii_letters)])
```