# Python - Basic validation of international names?

Tags: python, regex, django

Given a name string, I want to validate a few basic conditions: 
-The characters belong to a recognized script/alphabet (Latin, Chinese, Arabic, etc) and aren't say, emojis. 
-The string doesn't contain digits and is of length < 40

I know the latter can be accomplished via regex but is there a unicode way to accomplish the first? Are there any text processing libraries I can leverage?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15558392/3346095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check this using the [Unicode Character classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#CategoryOrBlock) in regex.

```
[\p{P}\s\w]{40,}
```

The most important part here is the \w character class using Unicode mode:

> `\p{P}` matches any kind of punctuation character
>   `\s` matches any kind of invisible character (equal to `[\p{Z}\h\v]`)
>   `\w` match any word character in any script (equal to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`)

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFdTt6/1)

You may want to add more like `\p{Sc}` to match currency symbols, etc.

But to be able to take [advantage of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties), you need to use the [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (an alternative to the standard re module) that supports Unicode codepoint properties with the `\p{}` syntax.

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import regex as re

regex = r"[\p{P}\s\w]{40,}"

test_str = ("Wow cool song!Wow cool song!Wow cool song!Wow cool song!  \nWow cool song! Wow cool song! Wow cool song! \n")   
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

PS: .NET Regex gives you some more options like \p{IsGreek}.

Comment: Sorry, I had some problems to add the Arab and Chinese characters but you can find some in the live demo.