# Counting only the frequency of letters in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, count, key

I am trying to make my program count everything but numbers in a string, and store it in a dictionary.

So far I have this:

```
string = str(input("Enter a string: "))
stringUpper = string.upper()

dict = {}
for n in stringUpper:
    keys = dict.keys()
    if n in keys:
        dict[n] += 1
    else:
        dict[n] = 1
print(dict)
```

I just want the alphabetical numbers quantified, but I cannot figure out how to exclude the non-alphabetical characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if character in string is a letter? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558392/how-to-check-if-character-in-string-is-a-letter-python)

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are multiple steps involved:

- Getting rid of the chars that you don't want to count
- Count the remaining

You have several options available to do these. I'll just present one option, but keep in mind that there might be other (and better) alternatives.

```
from collections import Counter

the_input = input('Enter something')
Counter(char for char in the_input.upper() if char.isalpha())
```

For example:

```
Enter something: aashkfze3f8237rhbjasdkvjuhb

Counter({'A': 3,
         'B': 2,
         'D': 1,
         'E': 1,
         'F': 2,
         'H': 3,
         'J': 2,
         'K': 2,
         'R': 1,
         'S': 2,
         'U': 1,
         'V': 1,
         'Z': 1})
```

So it obviously worked. Here I used [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count and a generator expression using [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) as condition to get rid of the unwanted characters.

Note that there are several bad habits in your code that will make your life more complicated than it needs to be:

- `dict = {}` will shadow the built-in `dict`. So it's better to choose a different name.
- `string` is the name of a built-in module, so here a different name might be better (but not `str` which is a built-in name as well).
- `stringUpper = string.upper()`. In Python you generally don't use camelCase but use `_` to seperate word (i.e. `string_upper`) but since you only use it to loop over you might as well use `for n in string.upper():` directly.
- Variable names like `n` aren't very helpful. Usually you can name them `char` or `character` when iterating over a string or `item` when iterating over a "general" iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re to replace all non-alphabetical characters before doing any manipulation:

```
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
#First parameter is the replacement, second parameter is your input string
regex.sub('', stringUpper )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check string for alphanumeric

```
n.isalnum()
```

for aphabetic:

```
n.isalpha()
```

So your code will be like:

```
dict = {}
for n in stringUpper:
    if n.isalpha():
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
        print(dict)
     else:
        #do something....
```

Answer (score 0):

string = str(input("Enter a string: "))

```
stringUpper = string.upper()

dict = {}
for n in stringUpper:
    if n not in '0123456789':
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in stringUpper:
    if n.isalpha()
        dict[n] += 1
    else:
        dict[n] = 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some comments and explanation. It will help understand the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating, check if the `lower()` and `upper()` is the same for a character. If they are different from each other, then it is an alphabetical letter.

```
if n.upper() == n.lower():
    continue
```

This should do it.