# How do I check to make sure there are no letters in my string?

Tags: python, string, find

Let's say I have string:

`string1 = "h      \\\\\ 2*2"`

How do I check the string to make sure it doesn't have any letters, regardless of capitlization.

So like

I have

```
if "a" in string1 or "A" in string1:
    print("it's got an A bro")
elif "b" in string1 or "B" in string1:
    print("it's got a B bro")
#cont...
else:
    print("There no letters in ur string bro")
```

There's gotta be a faster way to do this I assume. I am only looking for letters. Everything else can stay. like "\" or "*" those are good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if character in a string is a letter? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558392/how-can-i-check-if-character-in-a-string-is-a-letter-python)

Comment: @AMC yes thank you very much love ya babe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex search is probably the simplest way:

```
string1 = "h      \\\\\ 2*2"
if not re.search(r'^.*[A-Za-z].*$', string1):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: wow that's fancy. i've never seen something so cool like that it's what I've always dreamed of when coding

Comment: @Dr.SuessOfficial Not really `:-)` ... even the cat in the hat could figure it out.

Comment: maybe one day hopefully

Comment: _A regex search is probably the simplest way_ Wouldn’t a loop with `str.isalpha()` be simpler, and more versatile?

Comment: @AMC Performance should be somewhat similar, and I would much rather maintain a single clean one-liner than a loop, wouldn't you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _I would much rather maintain a single clean one-liner than a loop, wouldn’t you_ Only a single one? Sure, maybe. What happens when there’s more than one, though? Also, did you intend to use `re.match()` or `re.fullmatch()` instead of `re.search()` ? If you’re sticking with the latter option, why not just use `not re.search(r"[A-z]", string1)` ? Wouldn’t the effect be the same?

Comment: Never mind the fact, of course, that both regex solutions fail on characters such as `é` and `à`, which can hardly be described as rare.